# how to animate height to value 'auto' of mounted/unmounted react component using react-spring and transition

Tags: reactjs, transition, react-spring

is there a way of animating height from 0 to 'auto' of a newly mounted component using react-spring transition? After research I found only a workaround by animating max-height instead of height.

working example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-usetransition-example-forked-zknx6v?file=/src/index.js